# JsonMappingException: (was NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.domain.ProfitStrategyInputMsg["productBasicInfo"])

Tags: java, json

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was
>   java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain:
>   com.domain.profit.ProfitStrategyInputMsg["productBasicInfo"])

```
public List<ProfitStrategyInputMsg> buiInputParams() {

String paramStragetyA = "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";

        List<ProfitStrategyInputMsg> params = JsonUtil.toList(
                new String(Base64.decodeBase64(paramStragetyA.getBytes())), ProfitStrategyInputMsg.class);//Exception throw  why???

        System.out.println(JsonUtil.toString(params));

        return params;
    }




public class ProfitStrategyInputMsg {
    private int coverFlag;
    private List<ProductBasicInfo> productBasicInfo;

    public int getCoverFlag() {
        return coverFlag;
    }

    public void setCoverFlag(int coverFlag) {
        this.coverFlag = coverFlag;
    }

    public List<ProductBasicInfo> getProductBasicInfo() {
        return productBasicInfo;
    }

    public void setProductBasicInfo(List<ProductBasicInfo> productBasicInfo) {
        this.productBasicInfo = productBasicInfo;
    }}
```

how should i fix this ?? could someOne help

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ProductBasicInfo {

    private int productId;

    private List<Integer> bookCities;

    private int departureCity;

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateJsonSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateJsonDeserializer.class)
    private List<Date> departureDate;
}
```

change

```
public class ProductBasicInfo {

    private int productId;

    private List<Integer> bookCities;

    private int departureCity;

    private List<Date> departureDate;
}
```

Comment: Is it an answer? Actually the question does not have original declaration of `class ProductBasicInfo`. Probably it should be added to the question.